# How can I check whether key value pair match regardless of case?

Tags: javascript, hash

I'm creating a very simple program that displays English phrases and the user types in the Spanish translation. The phrases are like this:

```
const phrases = {
  "Hello": "Hola",
  "Goodbye" : "Adios",
  //etc...
}
```

And the matching logic:

```
Spanish_Phrases.prototype.calculate = function() {
  this.answer = (document.getElementById("answer").value);
  var question = $("#question").text();
  var questionMatcher = phrases[question].toString();
  var answerMatcher = this.answer;
  if (questionMatcher.ToLowerCase() == answerMatcher.ToLowerCase()) {
    alert("Correct!")
  } else {
    alert("Try again");
  }
}
```

The HTML is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spanish</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <script src="./src/spanish.js">
        </script>
        <link href="skeleton.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <section>
            <h2>Spanish Quiz</h2>
            <h3 id="question"></h3>
      <button type="button" id="questionbutton">Get English Phrase</button>
            <form action="#" id="form" name="form" onsubmit="return false;">
                Type Spanish translation...<br>
                <input id="answer" name="answer" type="text"><br>
                <br>
                <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </section>
    </center>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
```

However at the moment if the user enters the answer with the incorrect case, it's marked as wrong. That's why I've tried to use 'ToLowerCase' but it is saying it's not a function. I'm using it on a string, and when I debug in the console it shows that they are stings, but yet this throws an error. Am I missing something completely obvious in my code? Help would be much appreciated, thanks !

Comment: It's toLowerCase() not ToLowerCase().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.ToLowerCase()` – is not a function, cause in camelcase you must start with a lowercase letter, so it should be `.toLowerCase()`